# I can't make what I type to pdf

Tags: math-mode

I can't make pdf I type this :

‎‎

```
$‎E(‎\frac{1}{2}‎\Phi ‎+‎\frac{1}{2}‎\Phi‎‎\prime ‎,‎\frac{1}{2}‎\Psi ‎+‎\frac{1}{2}‎\Psi‎‎\prime‎)\leq ‎‎\frac{1}{2}E(‎\Phi , ‎‎‎‎\Psi‎‎\prime‎)+‎\frac{1}{2}E(‎\Phi‎‎\prime ‎,‎\Psi‎).‎‎$‎

\begin{eqmarray}‎‎
‎‎$‎\sum‎_‎{u\in‎\Sigma‎(0,‎\Gamma‎) }‎\frac{1}{|‎\Gamma‎_u | }E_{u,‎\Phi‎}‎‎‎(‎\Psi‎(u)) ‎‎$‎

‎‎$‎‎~&=&‎\sum_‎{u\in ‎\Sigma‎(0,‎\Gamma‎)  }‎\frac{1}{|‎\Gamma‎_u| }‎\sum‎‎\underline{‎v‎\in‎\Sigma‎_u(0) }m((u,v))f(d(‎\Psi‎(u),‎\Phi‎(v)))‎‎$‎

‎‎$‎~&=&‎\sum\_‎{u\in‎\Sigma‎(0,‎\Gamma‎)  }‎\frac{1}{|‎\Gamma‎_u| }\sum‎_{‎\eta‎\in‎\Sigma‎(1),‎u‎\subset‎‎\eta ‎}‎‎\frac{m(\eta)}{2}‎f(d(‎\Psi‎(u),‎\Phi‎(‎\eta‎ -u)))‎,‎‎$‎

‎‎$‎~&=‎&‎\sum‎‎_{\eta\in‎\Sigma‎(1,‎\Gamma‎)  }‎\frac{m(‎\eta‎ }{2|‎\Gamma‎_\eta | }‎\sum‎‎_{u\in‎\Sigma‎(0),u\subset‎\eta‎ }‎f(d(‎\Psi‎(u),‎\Phi‎(\eta -‎u)))‎‎$‎

‎‎$‎‎~‎&=&‎‎\sum‎‎_{(u,v)\in‎\Sigma‎(1,‎\Gamma‎)  }‎\frac{m((u,v))}{2|‎\Gamma‎_(u,v)| }(f(d(‎\Psi‎(u),‎\Phi‎(v)))+f(d(‎\Psi‎(v),‎\Phi‎(u)))‎‎$‎

‎‎$‎~&=&‎\sum‎‎_{(u,v)\in‎\Sigma‎(1,‎\Gamma‎)  }‎\frac{m((u,v))}{|‎\Gamma‎_(u,v) }f(d(‎\Psi‎(u),‎\Phi‎(v)))‎‎$‎

‎‎$‎~&=&E(‎\Phi ‎,‎\Psi‎).‎‎$‎

\end{eqmarray}‎‎‎
```

please help me

Comment: Try `eqnarray` instead of `eqmarray.` But in fact  `eqnarray` is not what you should be using. `align` is better. See  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: and inside `eqnarray` or `align` you should not use `$` you are already in math mode and you may not have blank lines. But please always post complete documents and say exactly what error you got, so we can reproduce it.

Comment: I simple introduction to LaTeX also seems to be in order...

Comment: @SeanAllred which will tell you all about U+200E I'm sure:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The 'also' might be pertinent...?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, although it is still a little wide for the page

Note that you had one "hidden" error in addition to the general syntax errors,
each of your `\sum_` is the unicode sequence

```
  U+005c REVERSE SOLIDUS
  U+0073 LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U
  U+006d LATIN SMALL LETTER M
  U+200e LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
  U+200e LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
  U+005f LOW LINE
```

The two left-to-right mark characters meant that the subscript was not seen as a subscript of the summation sign, but of an empty math atom to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
E(\frac{1}{2}\Phi +\frac{1}{2}\Phi' ,\frac{1}{2}\Psi +\frac{1}{2}\Psi')\leq \frac{1}{2}E(\Phi , \Psi')+\frac{1}{2}E(\Phi' ,\Psi)
\]

\begin{align*}
\sum_{u\in\Sigma(0,\Gamma)}\frac{1}{|\Gamma_u | }E_{u,\Phi}(\Psi(u)) \\
&=\sum_{u\in \Sigma(0,\Gamma)  }\frac{1}{|\Gamma_u| }\sum\underline{v\in\Sigma_u(0) }m((u,v))f(d(\Psi(u),\Phi(v)))\\
&=\sum_{u\in\Sigma(0,\Gamma)  }\frac{1}{|\Gamma_u| }\sum_{\eta\in\Sigma(1),u\subset\eta }\frac{m(\eta)}{2}f(d(\Psi(u),\Phi(\eta -u))),\\
&=\sum_{\eta\in\Sigma(1,\Gamma)  }\frac{m(\eta }{2|\Gamma_\eta | }\sum_{u\in\Sigma(0),u\subset\eta }f(d(\Psi(u),\Phi(\eta -u)))\\
&=\sum_{(u,v)\in\Sigma(1,\Gamma)  }\frac{m((u,v))}{2|\Gamma_{(u,v)}| }(f(d(\Psi(u),\Phi(v)))+f(d(\Psi(v),\Phi(u)))\\
&=\sum_{(u,v)\in\Sigma(1,\Gamma)  }\frac{m((u,v))}{|\Gamma_{(u,v)}|}f(d(\Psi(u),\Phi(v)))\\
&=E(\Phi ,\Psi).
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```